# mysql php private message system duplicatee rows

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everyone I have a problem in mysql I have to do a search on two user1 and user2 fields with the same variable (3) and I would not not copy the two fields

table name pm:

```
id    user1    user2    message    timestamp    user1read    user2read
1       3        4     edfdfdfdf      1            yes          no
2       3        5     ererererer     1            yes          no
3       5        3     gfffgfgdfdfd   1            yes          no
4       6        3     ewwwewewe      1            yes          no
5       7        3    ewwwewddfdfewe  1            yes          no
6       3        7    ewwwewddffewe   1            yes          no
```

I tried so

```
$q= mysqli_query("SELECT DISTINCT user1,user2 FROM pm WHERE (user1='3') or (user2='3') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

and he print:

```
user1 user2
3      4
3      5
5      3
6      3
7      3
3      7
```

I want print

```
user1 user2
3      4
3      5
6      3
7      3
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question you have? It's fairly unclear...

Comment: I have changed I hope it is more clear what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please give this query a try.

```
SELECT user1,user2
FROM pm T1 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT MIN(id) as min_id,
         LEAST(user1,user2) as id1,
         GREATEST(user1,user2) as id2
  FROM pm
  WHERE user1 = 3
  OR user2 = 3
  GROUP BY id1,id2)T2
ON T1.id = T2.min_id
ORDER BY T1.id ASC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fd88/1

What the query does is with a subquery it finds minimum id of userid 3's conversations with other people grouping by smaller userid and larger userid.  Then it joins back with pm table grabbing the user1 and user2 ids of these minimum ids.

What you're looking for is essentially userids of first messages between userid 3 and other people.

Comment: not sure ..try it without the (') single quotes since you're just looking at numbers anyways

Comment: try looping through and print out user1 and user2 in php see if you can get that to work